# Entity Framework. SaveChanges override. Tracker return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want set some properties for my model class in `SaveChanges`.

My code

`selectedEntityList` is always null, but record is added to the database.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var selectedEntityList = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x=> x.State == EntityState.Added);

    foreach (var entity in selectedEntityList)
    {
        var type = entity.GetType();
        var properites = entity.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach(var pr in properites.Where(p=>p.Name=="Position"))
        {
            pr.SetValue(type, "150", null);
        } 
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: remove ".Where(x=> x.State == EntityState.Added)" and try please.

Comment: Unfortunately, did not help

Comment: `pr.SetValue(type, "150", null);` should be `pr.SetValue(entity, "150", null);`

Comment: Why use `Where()` when you already know there can be no more than one `Position` property? Use `SingleOrDefault()` and check for `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, code works fine. Thank you all!

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
 {
     var selectedEntityList = ChangeTracker.Entries();
     foreach (var entity in selectedEntityList)
     {
         var type = entity.GetType();
         var properites = entity.Entity.GetType().GetProperties();
         var pr = properites.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Position");
            pr.SetValue(entity.Entity, 150, null);
     }
     return base.SaveChanges();
 }
```